# Base de datos de red social

Tags: base-de-datos

Me surge una duda, es en las reacciones que se hacen a la publicación y a los `usuarios`-`contactos`:

Diseñar una base de datos relacional que contemple lo siguiente:

> *Almacenamiento de usuarios (nombre completo, fecha de nacimiento, correo electrónico, teléfonos, descripción, estudios, lugar de residencia, lugar detrabajo)
>
> *Contactos de los usuarios (incluyendo fecha de agregación/aceptación de contacto)
>
> *Contactos pueden publicar información en las páginas de otros usuarios, si ese usuario tiene permiso de publicación abierto, en caso de que la publicación sea permitida, se debe de guardar el contacto que publica, a quien se lo publica, el contenido y la fecha de publicación.
>
> *Usuarios pueden indicar un estado (gusta, sorprende, molesta, no gusta) a las publicaciones de las paginas de sus contactos.
>
> Su base de datos debe ser modelada respetando la teoría de diseño de base de datos, y debe validar los campos.

Comment: Hola @AnthonyStark bienvenido a [es.so], me surge una pregunta, ¿exactamente cuál es tu petición? Para poder ayudarte de una manera más puntual, por favor agrega más detalles a tu pregunta, así como los avances que tengas hasta el momento. De igual forma te recomiendo tomar el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) así como revisar el [centro de ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help) para que conozcas las reglas del sitio.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, verás estoy iniciando mi curso y nos dejaron esta pequeña base de datos, solo tengo las tablas usuario, contacto y publicación, para la tabla de publicación no se como hacerle en el momento que dice "Si lo tiene permitido se puede realizar la publicación". Igual en las reacciones, no encuentro la forma, imaginaba que van en una sola tabla, pero, siempre va a regresar todas no? así que también podrían ser distintas tablas cada reacción, en si quiero algo de ayuda para saber que hacer, o un ejemplo aunque no sea igual, pero algo parecido para entender. agradezco tu ayuda

Comment: Bien, si ya tienes avances está perfecto, ahora, te sugiero que enfoques tu pregunta a aquellas partes en donde tienes dudas. Esto es debido a que esto parece más una petición que una pregunta, poco a poco verás como es el funcionamiento del sitio y preguntas tan amplias regularmente son cerradas, mientras tanto sugiero que [edites tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/55140/edit) pongas exclusivamente aquellas partes donde te genera duda, también debes poner segmentos de código de lo que has intentado y que tus dudas sean muy puntuales para poder ayudarte de una mejor manera :)

Comment: Seria útil ver el diagrama de tu ddbb que tienes pensads

Answer (score 1):

Esto no pretende ser una respuesta completa, pero tu esquema de datos debiera ser ahi:

**Tabla usuario**

```
id (PK)  nombre | fechanacimiento | correo | teléfonos | descripción | estudios | residencia | trabajo
```

**Tabla contactos**

```
id (PK) | id_contacto1 (FK contacto.id) | id_contacto2 (FC contacto.id | fecha | permiso_publicacion
```

Aquí he definido que "permiso_publicacion" es el permiso mutuo que se dan los usuarios para publicar cada uno en la página del otro.

**Tabla publicaciones**

```
id (PK) | id_dueño_pagina (FK contacto.id) | id_publicador (FC contacto.id) | contenido | fecha
```

**Tabla Reacciones**

```
id (PK) | id_publicacion (FK publicaciones.id) | id_usuario (FP usuario.id | reaccion
```

Respecto a la regla específica:

> Contactos pueden publicar información en las páginas de otros
>   usuarios, si ese usuario tiene permiso de publicación abierto

Eso no tiene nada de relacional. Se hace con lógica de negocios en la capa de aplicación. *Se puede implementar* con un CHECK, pero sin saber si la BBDD lo soporta, es una majadería y está fuera del alcance de la pregunta.